# Using ui-grid to show large data sets?

Tags: angularjs, dataset, angular-ui-grid

AngularJS platform, needing to show 1000 rows of sata and upwards of 500 columns of data. ui-grid does everything else I need but tends to freeze with a large amount of columns. I was thinking of scoping the grid window to only show 10 columns at a time and 'paginate' left and right requesting the next set of columns each time, but not entirely sure how I would do that. I'm not looking for a direct how to do this as much as I am looking to generate discussion about it to help kickstart my brain.

http://ui-grid.info

Comment: I think what I am going to do is store the whole dataset in variable X and only push the first 10 columns to the grid. I'll set up pagination buttons that will redraw the grid, for the next/previous 10 columns. It should be fairly quick. Need to look into refresh/redrawing uiGrid. I think they have an api command for it, that will accept the updated data.

Comment: try angulargrid - http://www.angulargrid.com/example.html, much faster, but there is no grid you can control how grid is render (eg., only render particular amount of rows / columns you wanted, its depend on how grid designed)

Comment: Oh btw, I have my own PoC of 1M rows x 1M columns rendering (only render what you see) - http://rawgit.com/S-YOU/doTA/master/examples/virtual-scroll/index.html - but its not really a grid.

Comment: @YOU thats an awesome example, but how did you do it? Not actually using Angular Grid?

Comment: you are right that is not angular grid. Its just a prove of concept of possibility of virtual rows and virtual columns, which most of grid does not do. for virtual rows, I update tag attributes and text nodes when you scroll. for virtual columns, I replace/insert the html tags. unfortunately, I don't have good writing or paper for that purpose, except library [source code](https://github.com/S-YOU/doTA)